# css3 columns need much time to render if many divs inside

Tags: html, performance, css

I created a bootstrap based html/css construct and working with columns for a pinterst-like design.

Using the solution from here:
https://blog.kulturbanause.de/2014/03/responsive-pinterest-style-layout-mit-css3/#more-12065

```
.content {
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-count: 1;
  column-gap: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width:650px) {
  .content {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:960px) {
  .content {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
  .content {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    max-width:1460px;
  }
}
```

Every tile has a simple structure:

```
<article class="post default-tile">
    <h2 class="">TITLE</h2>
        <div class="tile-img-wrapper">
            <img src="imgpath" class="tile-img" alt="alternative name" />
        </div>
        <div class="tiles-content" data-ref="someurl">
            mycontent
        </div>
       <? /* <div class="like-buttons">
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="permalink" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="240" data-show-faces="false"></div>
            <g:plusone href="permalink" size="medium"></g:plusone>
        </div>
        */ ?>
    </article>
```

As you can see I disabeld the socialmedia buttons for test reason, also to exclude this from the performance issue.

The images are not defined, so also no issue.

I am loading like 20 to 25 tiles on start page.

**What I tried**

I set the `.post` css `width: 271px`. This increases the performance enormously. The problem is, that the site does not look that pretty in some screen/window withs.

**So** my qeustion is, how could I archive the same representation, when calculating the tile-with by the browser-rendering in the same speed, as if I define the with directly.

Has anybody experienced the same issue?

Comment: defining the `width` in relative units?

Comment: @dippas I will give it a try, but I think it is problematic, becausr I have a fix max-width which creates different space with as "marin" for the columncontainer...

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?